# ASP.NET Dropdownlist expands past the screen

Tags: asp.net, webforms, drop-down-menu, web-controls

The issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916297/dropdownlist-in-ie9-and-ff-expands-past-monitor), totally my case. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apply a CSS class using overflow:hidden

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. My dropdownlist is created dynamically from the code, can it influence the problem somehow? Other CSS properties for the dropdownlist work ok though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive about this, but you should be able to specify a CSS style for list options.

```
option {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width:200px;        
}
```

Like Matt said, you can also use `overflow:hidden` to truncate anything past a certain point.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Neither does overflow:hidden.. My dropdownlist is created dynamically from the code, can it influence the problem somehow? Other CSS properties for the dropdownlist work ok though.